# d3.js. To show dataset number in locale format

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dataset array of numbers:

```
var dataset = [ 2147000, 3750000, 3434000, 3095000, 8132000, 8875000, 7727000, 6605000 ];
```

And locale definition:

```
var ES = d3.locale (…)
```

I have this code for render dataset:

```
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
```

I want to show the numbers in locale format but I dont know how to tell it to function(d)

This is a codepen working. I want to show in local format the tags inside bars. (line 65)
http://codepen.io/aitormendez/pen/xRVNMb?editors=0010

I tried `ES.numberFormat("$,.")`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ES.numberFormat("$,.")` that you use as `tickFormat` is a function, and given an argument (a number) it will return a formatted string given the specified format. So you format the number `1000000` you simply use the function by calling `ES.numberFormat("$,.")(d)(1000000)`.

To implement in your code:

```
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return ES.numberFormat("$,.")(d);
    })
```

An even better way would be to declare the function as

```
var nbrFormat = ES.numberFormat("$,.");
```

And then use

```
.tickFormat(nbrFormat);
```

and

```
return nbrFormat(d);
```

To limit your declaration of the format to one place, instead of two.

See https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md

Comment: Look [here](http://koaning.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/html/d3format.html) for more information

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for de solution and the references.